# Sum columns where colum_x is the same

Tags: mysql

I am using the following MYSQL to retrieve data:

```
 SELECT `units`, `developer_proceeds` * `units` AS `developer_proceeds`, `customer_currency`, `country_code` FROM daily_raw WHERE `begin_date` = "2014-03-13"
```

And I get the following result:

```
     INSERT INTO `daily_raw` (`units`, `units`, `customer_currency`, `country_code`) VALUES
(2.00, 0.0000, 'USD', 'CO'),
(1.00, 0.0000, 'MXN', 'MX'),
(5.00, 0.0000, 'USD', 'US'),
(11.00, 0.0000, 'USD', 'AR'),
(19.00, 0.0000, 'MXN', 'MX'),
(1.00, 4.2000, 'USD', 'PE'),
(9.00, 0.0000, 'USD', 'PE'),
(2.00, 8.4000, 'USD', 'AR'),
(1.00, 0.0000, 'USD', 'US'),
(18.00, 0.0000, 'EUR', 'ES'),
(1.00, 4.2000, 'USD', 'US');
```

How can I group data together for the same country_code?

E.g.

```
 (2.00, 0.0000, 'USD', 'CO'),
    (20.00, 0.0000, 'MXN', 'MX'),
    (7.00, 4.2000, 'USD', 'US'),
    (10.00, 4.2000, 'USD', 'PE'),
    (13.00, 8.4000, 'USD', 'AR'),
    (18.00, 0.0000, 'EUR', 'ES'),
```

Comment: Does MYSql allows duplicate column names? i am bit confused..

Answer (score 0):

Select the *sum* of the calculations and group by the rest:

```
SELECT
    sum(`units`) as units,
    sum(`developer_proceeds` * `units`) AS `developer_proceeds`,
    `customer_currency`,
    `country_code`
FROM daily_raw
WHERE `begin_date` = "2014-03-13" 
GROUP BY 3, 4 -- FYI, these are column numbers
```

If you want aggregation of everything from the country in one row, delete columns 1 and 3 from both the select and the group by clause

Answer (score 0):

You would use `group by`.  If I correctly understand what you are doing:

```
SELECT sum(units), sum(developer_proceeds` * `units) AS `developer_proceeds`,
       `customer_currency`, `country_code`
FROM daily_raw
WHERE `begin_date` = '2014-03-13'
GROUP BY country_code, customer_currency;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT sum(units), sum(developer_proceeds` * `units) AS `developer_proceeds`,
       `customer_currency`, `country_code`
FROM daily_raw
WHERE `begin_date` = '2014-03-13'
GROUP BY country_code, customer_currency;
```